# Nginx - always pass query string

Tags: php, nginx

I'm running a website which uses query params to identify different affiliates, and i need those params to be passed through-out my entire website.

I'm trying to avoid having to write something like:

```
<a href="somepage.php?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>">link</a>
```

for every link i have in my site.
Is there a possibility to "add" this to ALL internal and external links through nginx or even php?

Thanks

Comment: You really should be capturing the data on your landing page and storing it in the session.

Comment: And what about external links?